# How to use two different colorbox style on same page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new in this forum plus I'm a beginner in HTML codes,

I made 2 different popup FORMS with 2 different designs (with the software WEB FORM BUILDER)

I face a problem with Colorbox.js : I had 2 colorboxes styles on the same page.

My problem is : once I click on the first popup link it always display  the colorbox style of the second popuplink.

I would like to know witch code I can put into my "HEAD" and my "Colorbox.css" to use two or multiple colorboxes style inside the same page !!

HERE IS AN EXAMPLE TO EXPLAIN MY PROBLEM : http://junopanda.livehost.fr/index.html

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not a user of colorbox I can't say for sure but it seems as if the pop up boxes being generated have the same class and therefore the same css is being applied to both.

The line in your HEAD section that makes me suspect this is `$fb_pop(".fb_iframe").` which appears on both of your colorbox invocations (which only seem to differ in the height aspect and nothing else)